# Center DIV horizontally with margin

Tags: css, margin

For some reason, I cannot center the .`logo` class with CSS.

I've tried `margin:0px auto`.

Am I overlooking something?

Thanks.

**CSS:**

```
.full {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.logo {
    width: 230px;
    height: 117px;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 15px auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="full"> 

<figure class="logo"></figure> 
<figure class="x-button"></figure>

</div>
```

Comment: Remove `float: left;` for `.logo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` for `.logo`. `float: left` makes it align to the left.

Click [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/DmmCK/) for a demo fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the following:

```
.logo {
    float: left;
}
```

You cannot directly center a floated element via `margin:0px auto;`. If you want an element to be floated **and** center, you can always apply the margin to the parent while the child itself keeps the float. [**An example of this can be seen here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHs6t/)

Keep in mind, if it is just text you are trying to center, you can always just use: `text-align:center;`

Comment: I wanted to mention about centering the parent too, but in this case the parent also has a `float: left;`. But then OP can modify that if there is no need to float the parent :)

Comment: @Harry good point, in this case you would either make a wrapper around the child... or you would just apply the margin to the parent's parent..(grand-parent.).. **Basically, you are just applying the margin to the element above the float** In the event of two floats, apply it to the higher float.

Answer (score 1):

At least in this case, you can not center a floated element horizontally.

Here is a minimal example: http://jsfiddle.net/tJ5N3/

You can remove the floating, as others said above.

Also, as a workaround, you can wrap your element with a `div` that is horizontally centered. In this case, your can keep your floating, if it is necessary.